# Android Bluetooth Connection and Receiving Data

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am developing an Android application in which it receives list of paired devices. I want to start a connection with the device clicked by user, from the list of available devices. Therefore, I show the list of paired devices to the user and then by clicking on one of them, the application should start listening and receiving data in CSV format from that selected device.

I have done a lot of search about this issue but I just became confused more and more.  What should I do in `onItemClickListener` method in order to get what I want?

Here is my code:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

                String info = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
                String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
                BluetoothDevice device = myBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
                    try {
                        Log.d("pairDevice()", "Start Pairing...");
                        Class cl = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
                        Class[] par = {};
                        Method method = cl.getMethod("createBond", par);
                        Object[] args = {};
                        method.invoke(device, args);


                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }

                    BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
                    BluetoothSocket mmSocket = null;
                    final UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("fc5ffc49-00e3-4c8b-9cf1-6b72aad1001a");
                    // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
                    // given BluetoothDevice
                    try {
                        tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                        Method m;
                        try {
                            m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
                            tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
                        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mmSocket = tmp;
                }
                }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This link might help you http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingDevices